# How can i retrive the post by tags in New theme that is using another post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I retrieve the post by tags in New theme that is using another post_type

For example, I am building a cinema site..

The site is

For movies - I am using post - The movies are post there..
For actors - I am using post_type : persoane , Taxonomy : lista.

How can I retrieve the movies play by bruce willis in

---

This movie have Bruce Willis Tag....( this is a regular post in wp)

In Bruce Willis page I want to retrieve the movie.... that have Bruce Willis Tag

In conclusion I want to display the movies that actor play in

I anny body know please help.

Comment: if you have SQL
use this 
`$title = "Bruce Willis"
$sql = "Select * from  table_table where tags like '{$title}'";
$run = mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: look at this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/retrive-post-by-tags-php-code?replies=1

Comment: Which template file is being used to show your persons ?

Comment: The template is actors  <?php
/*
Template Name Posts: Actori
*/
?>

Comment: Can you show the code of actors.php ?

Comment: it contains more php link of tabs... etc...  this is the code that shoud display link to the movies...

Comment: this is the code... http://wordpress.org/support/topic/retrive-post-by-tags-php-code?replies=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but you can give it a try

```
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'lista',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => get_query_var('term')
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo  the_title().'<br />';
    echo the_content();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

[**Take a look at this.**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters)

Comment: ok thanks, but one thing the lista taxanomy is for actors taxonomy...
the movies are regular posts... they are added by Post in WP

Comment: If you didn't get the solution please try to post your question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) with proper information.